# How to get navbar after logo?

Tags: magento2.3, navigation, porto-theme

I am using Porto theme, In Porto the navbar is after the header block. Now, I want the navbar after the logo. How can I do that,
here is the default.xml

```
    <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_custom_head" template="html/head.phtml" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_header" template="html/header.phtml" before="main.content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Form\Login" name="header_customer_form_login" ifconfig="porto_settings/header/login_popup" template="Smartwave_Porto::html/login.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="custom_block" template="html/header_custom_block.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/header/static_block" after="-"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="navigation.sections" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="top.search" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="minicart" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="logo" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="page.top" destination="page.wrapper" after="porto_header"/>

    <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="1"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="1"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" remove="1"/>

    <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="footer_block" template="html/footer.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="footer.store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="subscribe_footer.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="custom_link" before="-" template="html/custom_link.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
```